# In F#, how to implement an interface with parent and grandparent interfaces?

Tags: inheritance, interface, f#

When multiple interfaces are being inherited, what is the correct way of implementing them in F#?

For Example, assume the following interface hierarchy, the implementation of ITranscript on the type TranscriptNote gives:

***"The value or constructor 'tservice' is not defined."***

```
type TranscriptNote =
   {      
        tservice : Nullable<DateTime>      
   }
   interface ITranscript with 
       member this.tservice with get() = tservice and set value = tservice <- value 

"The value or constructor 'tservice' is not defined."

where ITranscript is :

type ITranscript =
    inherit ITablet
    abstract member note : byte[] with get
    abstract member transcript: string with get

type ITablet = 
    inherit IParagraph
    inherit IInk

type IParagraph = 
    inherit IEncounter
    abstract member paragraphTitle : string with get
    abstract member title : string with get

type IEncounter = 
    abstract member tservice : Nullable<DateTime> with get,set
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: @JL0PD has the correct explanation for the compiler error you're seeing. I've removed the incorrect information from my answer, but left the rest.**

One way is to implement each interface separately. Under each interface, implement only the members that are explicitly defined by that interface:

```ml
type IGrandparent =
    abstract member GetName : unit -> string

type IParent =
    inherit IGrandparent
    abstract member GetCount : unit -> int

type MyType() =
    interface IGrandparent with
        member __.GetName() = "name"
    interface IParent with
        member __.GetCount() = 1

let obj = MyType() :> IParent
printfn "%A" <| obj.GetName()
printfn "%A" <| obj.GetCount()
```

Note that I didn't implement `GetName` under `IParent`, but I can still call `GetName` on an `IParent` instance, thanks to inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Your type would look like that, if you want to compile it with original structure. But even if F# supports OOP, it doesn't mean that's always the best way, read [style guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/style-guide/) P 3 & 4. F# is not C# with different syntax, it's different language with different core principles. Maybe your hierarchy can be represented better with [DU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions)

```ml
// [<CLIMutable>] // uncomment this line to make all fields mutable
type TranscriptNote =
    {
        // instances can be mutated, but only this field
        mutable tservice : Nullable<DateTime>
    }
    interface ITranscript with
        // stubs
        member _.note = [| |] // empty array
        member _.paragraphTitle = "some title"
        member _.title = "some another title"
        member _.transcript = "some transcript"

        member this.tservice with get() = this.tservice // need 'this' to get access to field
                             and set value = this.tservice <- value
```

Notice: you don't have to implement each interface separately, but it may help in maintenance.

Comment: That's interesting. You are correct. I will update my answer accordingly.